# Find first highest salary employee under manager

Tags: sql, oracle

In the employee table data is stored as below

```
Empno ename  salary manager

1     prasad 100    4
2     durga  200    4
3     ggggg  200    4
4     jjjjj  300    6
5     kkkkk  600    6
6     dddddd 700    7
```

I need to find out the first highest salary employee under manager.

my sql code and output:

```
select * from employee where salary in
         (select max(salary) from employee group by manager);
```

output:

```
Empno ename  salary manager

2     durga  200    4
3     ggggg  200    4
5     kkkkk  600    6
6     dddddd 700    7
```

Expecting output should be:

```
2     durga  200    4
5     kkkkk  600    6
6     dddddd 700    7
```

because salary '200' displaying two times for two employees. My requirement is that display first highest salary employee only under manager.

Can anyone suggest sql query for my expecting output. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which one would be the "first employee"? `durga` or `ggggg`? Why?

Comment: either durga or ggggg is fine.I need only one row for each highest salary

Comment: Ummm why did you destroy all the formatting?

Comment: @AvinKavish didn't understand

Comment: Gordon formatted the code properly to make it readable, now it's just a wall of text.

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: Can you quantify what you mean by first employee? Do you mean the one with the lowest emp no?

Comment: either durga or ggggg is fine.I need only one row for each highest salary .
@AvinKavish that is also fine if you consider lowest emp no.my requirement is that only one record for each highest salary

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` window function. For example:

```
select 
  empno, ename, salary, manager
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by manager order by salary desc, ename) as rn
  from employee
) x where rn = 1
```

Comment: Which is the lowest cost, yours or Gordon's? explain analyse

Comment: That depends on a ton of parameters. engine model, presence of indexes, size of the table, up-to-date table stats, algorithm repertoire, and much, much more. Not a black & white answer.

Comment: This is a generic solution. You'll need to adapt it to your specific database engine. By the way, what database & version are you using?

Comment: using oracle db

Comment: Looks like The Impaler wins the SQL battle

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ename, manager, MAX(salary) FROM employee GROUP BY manager;
```

#### Live example:

- http://tpcg.io/HOpn7Z

---

**Edit:** Oracle Database

```
SELECT manager, MAX(salary) FROM employee GROUP BY manager;
```

Comment: This doesn't select the first employee, does it?

Comment: @user2155454 What is your database?

Comment: oracle database.getting below error
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Comment: Wait, this live example is in SQLite. This will not work as I stated earlier. You cannot have an aggregate function and other column selects that do not appear in a group by clause

Comment: @ℛɑƒæĿ ename,empno is missing

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery, rather than `group by`:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.salary = (select max(e2.salary)
                  from employee e2
                  where e2.manager = e.manager
                 );
```

Your issue is that a maximum salary under one manager may be the salary of someone else -- but not that manager's maximum.

Comment: still salary 200 displaying two times

Comment: This does not differentiate between duplicate salaries, does it? Final select is only constrained by salary.